# Desktop gadget css animation

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how to create an animation in desktop gadget properly ? Currently, I'm creating in css but it doesn't work at all. **When I tested in html it does work but it doesn't work in desktop gadget.** An animation i wanna create is something like this code below.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

```html
<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

<p><b>Note:</b> When an animation is finished, it changes back to its original style.</p>
```

Comment: CSS3 transitions and animations don't work in IE9

Comment: Is there any way to create an animation in desktop gadget ?